# How do I replace Consumes and Produces in Swashbuckle 5.0.0 using ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I need to refactor some C# code using Swashbuckle 4.0.1 and ASP.NET Core 2.0. I have to use Swashbuckle 5.0.0 and ASP.NET Core 3.1, however, I'm not able to solve the error I get from `Consumes` and `Produces`. The snippet I need to refactor is this:

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context) {
   var produces = context.ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out var mInfo) ? mInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ProducesAttribute>().FirstOrDefault() : null;

   if (produces != null) {
      operation.Consumes.Clear();                           /* ERROR */
      operation.Consumes = produces.ContentTypes.ToList();  /* ERROR */
      operation.Produces.Clear();                           /* ERROR */
      operation.Produces = produces.ContentTypes.ToList();  /* ERROR */
   }

   foreach (var parameter in operation.Parameters) {
      var description = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.First(p => p.Name == parameter.Name);
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Name))
         parameter.Name = description.ModelMetadata?.Name;
      if (parameter.Description == null && description.RouteInfo != null)
         parameter.Description = description.ModelMetadata?.Description;
      if (description.RouteInfo != null)
         parameter.Required |= !description.RouteInfo.IsOptional;
   }
}
```

I'm not able to understand how to get rid of those errors. The errors I obtain from Visual Studio are:

***Error CS1061 `OpenApiOperation` does not contain a definition for `Consumes`*** (the same happens with `Produces`) **and no accessible extension method `Consumes` accepting a first argument of type `OpenApiOperation` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: try rc version of nuget package open api

Comment: @shyamsundarsinghtomar the problem remains.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1296

Comment: @Helen I already read that article, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @FrancoScarpa Can you go through this link and try name space as mentioned and swagger packages ?                                             
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

You would have to decorate your controllers with Produces/Consumes attributes. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1296

Comment: The problem I'm facing is related to the methods only. I already read that article, but it didn't solve the problem, since it seems to focus on attributes only.